# A Gaussian process that is continuous in probability but not almost surely

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, continuity, normal-distribution

Let $(X_t)_{t\in [0,1]}$ be a Gaussian process. $(X_t)$ is continuous in probability if and only if its mean and autocovariance function are continuous on $[0,1]$. Continuity in probability does not imply continuity almost surely. But I cannot find an example of an $(X_t)$ that is continuous in probability but not almost surely. What is a classical counterexample?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's cheap counter example using Brownian motion.

Consider a standard Brownian motion $\{B_{t}\}$. Take $U$ a uniform random variable in $[0,1]$.
Define $$\tilde{B}_{t}=\begin{cases} 
B_{t} & t\neq U\\
0 & t=U\\
\end{cases}
$$

It's easy to see the finite distributions are the same as the standard Brownian motion and in particular $cov(\tilde{B}_t,\tilde{B}_s)= s \land t$. However, this process is a.s. discontious, as $$P(\{\tilde{B}_t\} \text{is continous} | U=u)= P(B_u=0)=0$$

Comment: I'm pretty sure you want your process to be defined as $\widetilde B_t=B_t$ if $t$ is **not** equal to $U$ and $0$ at $t=U$.  Otherwise your process definitely does not have the properties you claimed.

Comment: @W.Volante I think you are confusing something here: Just because it has the same covariances as Brownian Motion does not mean it is equal to Brownian Motion *as a process*. It only implies that all distributions of finite-dimensional projections agree. For the relationship between continuity in probability and sample path continuity, see the Wiki entry: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_process#Continuity It also essentially answers your question.

Answer (score 2):

In the following we consider a **separable** stationary Gaussian process $X=\{X(t),t\in\mathbb{R}\}$, which takes real values. For simplicity we assume that $\mathsf{E}[X(t)]=0$ and denote the covariance function of $X$ by $B(t)=\mathsf{E}[X(t)X(0)]$.

Now suppouse that the spectral density of $X$ is
\begin{equation*}
 f(\lambda)=\frac{1_{\{[3,\infty)\}}(\lambda)}{\lambda(\log\lambda)^2},\qquad \lambda\in\mathbb{R}_+,
\end{equation*}
and the covariance function of $X$ is
\begin{equation*}
 B(t)=\mathsf{E}[X(t)X(0)]=\int_{\mathbb{R}_+}\cos(t\lambda)f(\lambda)\, \mathrm{d}\lambda,
 \quad t\in\mathbb{R}.
\end{equation*}
Hence $B(t)$ is continuous in $t$, and $X$ is continuous in quadratic mean and continuous in probability.

On the other hand, using  Belyaev's result in paper "Local properties of the sample functions of stationary Gaussian processes, *Theor. Prob. Appl.*, **5**, 117-120.(1960) "
(**Theorem 3** If the stationary Gaussian process $X(t)$ has a spectral density $f(\lambda)$ such that
$f(\lambda)\ge C/(\lambda(\log \lambda )^2) $ for some C>0, $\lambda_0\ge0$ and all $\lambda \ge \lambda_0 $, then almost all sample function of $X$ are unbounded on any interval of finite length), $X$ is not continuous almost surely.

**Remark** Since FZan already provided an interesting example. Here we emphasize the separable process.

Comment: Thanks for the extra example! You seem knowledgeable about continuity of Gaussian processes, maybe you could have a look at this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4734402/a-counterexample-on-the-continuity-of-gaussian-processes-in-a-rather-complex-set